# Android progress bar with circular drawable and filling from bottom to top

Tags: java, android, progress-bar, android-custom-view, xml-layout

I am currently working on creating a custom progress bar and have so far managed to get the correct image I want to display, however I am trying to customise it so that it fill the white space within my drawable from bottom to top (bottom being 0 and top 100). I am using xml layouts.

I am not entirely sure if this is possible, the image I am trying to fill is;

[image]

Any guidance as to whether this is possible or if there are any libraries I would use that would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think you have to use a in ImageView (with a drawable) for the gradient background, and a customized progressbar overlaid on it. You might use a FrameLayout or a RelativeLayout to encapsulate the two.

Comment: Do you have any sort of sample code?

Comment: @RuchirBaronia I ended up just using a squared image with bordered image with transparent background